# How to use Octave to plot for birthday problem?

Tags: octave

I figured out I can write a function to calculate the probability of at least two share the same birthday:

```
function retval = bday (total, n)
    retval= 1- prod((total - n + 1: total)/total)
endfunction

octave:62> bday(365, 23)
retval = 0.5073
ans = 0.5073
```

Now if I hope to plot a 3d chart using `mesh`, where `total` is a vector `1000:100:2000`, and `n` is another vector `20:5:40`. How should I do it?

Comment: I guess by using mesh, as exactly you describe. What is the issue?

Comment: I saw example like `>>> x=linspace(-2,2,5);
>>> y=linspace(-2,2,5);
>>> [xx,yy]=meshgrid(x,y);
>>> mesh(xx,yy,4-(xx.^2+yy.^2))` For my case I am not quite sure how to apply my own `bday` function on that two vector.

Comment: just make a variable `zz` and fill it up, instead of aplying the equation in `mesh` directly

Comment: how? Can you give an example?

Comment: `zz(1,1)=bday(1000,20)`. Now just a couple of for loops for all desired values